# For what values of $a$ does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^ a}{1+n^3}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For what values of  $a$  does
> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^ a}{1+n^3}$$
> converge?
>
> Hint: For what value less than $a$, $a$ converges?

Here is my thought process:

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^ a}{1+n^3}= \lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^a}{1+n^3}=\frac{1^{a}}{(1+1^3)}+ \frac{1^{a}+\frac{1^{a}}{1+1^3}}{(1+2^3)}+\ldots$

Comment: The general term is asymptotic to $n^{a-3}$, convergence of $\sum n^p$ is well known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some basic results that gives you condition for the convergence of the series we obtain from a sequence $(n^\alpha)$, in particular we must have $\alpha<-1$ for the series to converge. You can see those things playing around with the harmonic and generalized harmonic series. The general term of you summation is asymptotically equal to $n^{a-3}$. So for the sum to converge we must have $a-3<-1$. We get $a<2$.